# Google Apps Scriptのスクリプトエディタでペーストができない

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome

GAS(1500行程度）を別のファイルにペーストして使っていました（テスト用→本番用のように）。
あるときからコピーはできるもののペースト（Contl+Vまたは右クリック）が出来なくなってしまいました（操作はできるものの結果には反映されない）。
PC(複数のWindowsマシン）を変えたりブラウザやアカウント(Chrome,Edge)を変えても結果は変わらず。一方メモ帳などのアプリへはペーストができます。
再起動やキャッシュの削除等は試しました。他に思い当たる原因をご存じの方はご教示お願い致します。

【追記】
少ない量だとペーストが出来ました(167行、5836文字）。一定量を超えるとペーストできなくなります。文字数を数えるサイトに貼り付けているときもブラウザを跨いでも同様でしたのでスクリプトエディタの問題ではなくPCの問題かもしれません。